# why string.matches["+-*/"] will report the pattern exception?

Tags: java, regex

I have this code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
       String et1 = "test";
       String et2 = "test";
       et1.matches("[-+*/]"); //works fine
       et2.matches("[+-*/]"); //java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException, why?
}
```

Because '-' is escape character? But why it will works fine, if '-' switchs with '+' ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`-` inside a character class (the `[xxx]`) is used to define a range, for example: `[a-z]` for all lower case characters. If you want to actually mean "dash", it has to be in first or last position. I generally place it first to avoid any confusions.

Alternatively you can escape it: `[+\\-*/]`.

Answer (score 4):

it is because `-` is used to define a range of characters in a character class. Since `+` is after `*` in the ascii table, the range has no sense, and you obtain an error.

To have a literal `-` in the middle of a character class, you must escape it. There is no problem if the `-` is at the begining or at the end of the class because it's unambigous.

An other situation where you don't need to escape the `-` is when you have a character class shortcut before, example:

```
[\\d-abc]
```

*(other regex engines like pcre allows the same when the character class shortcut is placed after `[abc-\d]`, but Java doesn't seem to allow this.)*

Answer (score 0):

Just FYI,  the Java regular expression meta characters are defined [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/literals.html):

```
The metacharacters supported by this API are: <([{\^-=$!|]})?*+.>
```

As a general rule, to save myself from regexp debugging headaches, if I want to use any of these characters as a literal then I precede them with a \  (Or \\ inside of a Java String expression).

Either:

```
et2.matches("[\\+\\-\\*/]");
```

Or:

```
et2.matches("[\\-\\+\\*/]");
```

Will work regardless of order.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use: [\-\+\*/]
Because: '-' to define range, eg: [a-d] it's mean: a,b,c,d

Comment: In this case it's unnecessary to escape anything inside the brackets actually.